# How to use the Shopify API to change the payment status of orders?

Tags: shopify

I'm building an iOS app for my own Shopify store. I created a private app and using the API key and password to call APIs with the format:

```
https://apikey:password@hostname/admin/resource.json
```

Problem occurs when I try to use the API to make the payment status change for orders.  (I can create a new order without problem). I don't find any API for changing the financial status of an order. I cannot change the financial status by modifying an order or I even cannot make any transaction by API no matter the "kind" of transactions is: "authorisation", "capture" or "sale".

So how can I change the financial status of an order using the API?

Here is an example for the request and response of using the API:

Object Called:

```
/admin/orders/#{order_id}/transactions.json
```

request:

```
{
    "transaction": {
        "amount": 50, 
        "test":true,
        "kind": "sale"
    }
}
```

response:

```
{"errors":{"kind":["sale is not a valid transaction"]}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create a transaction or modify the financial_status of any order created via the Shopify API. Refer http://docs.shopify.com/api/order which explicitly says this.

So essentially, you need to pass the financial_status as 'paid' when creating the order and in case your payment was not successful from the gateway, DELETE the order. http://docs.shopify.com/api/order.html#destroy

Answer (score 1):

Just a couple of things to try:

I noticed in the [Transaction doco](http://docs.shopify.com/api/transaction#create) there are quotes around the amount, which you don't have in your code (e.g. try "50.00" instead of 50):

```
POST /admin/orders/#{id}/transactions.json

{
  "transaction": {
    "amount": "10.00",
    "kind": "capture"
  }
}
```

Also, have you seen [this discussion](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-technology/t/how-enter-authorization-valid-order-and-transaction-usgin-api-185075) on the Shopify forums?

> ...it seems to work so long as **the amount of the transaction doesn't exceed the total outstanding balance of the order**. From what I have gathered you can not charge or create a transaction for more than the initial sale amount of the order...

Comment: Can u tell how I can update receiptJson/receipt field of payment

Answer (score 1):

I got some problem with changing the status of the order earlier , later i solved, to get rid of error you should take care of the following things.

Price of the order should be equal or less than the exact price of the order

1. *Price < exact order price, order will be labeled as Partial Paid*
2. *Price = to the exact order price , order will be labbeled as Paid*
3. *Paid Price > exact order price , you will get error*
4. Order with status paid, you will get error to change the status of
   payment

```html
POST /admin/orders/#{id}/transactions.json

{
  "transaction": {
    "amount": "10.00",
    "kind": "capture"
  }
}
```

```html
$order_get = $shopify('GET', '/admin/orders/'.$order_id.'.json' );
  
  $total_price = $order_get['total_price'];
  
  if( $order_get['financial_status'] != 'paid' ){
  
  
    $arguments = array( "order" => array(
         'note' => 'Paid'
         )
       );
    
    $order_put = $shopify('PUT', '/admin/orders/'.$order_id.'.json', $arguments);
    
    
    $arg  = array( "transaction" => array(
        "amount" => $total_price,
        "kind"   => "capture"
        )
      );
    
    $order_put = $shopify('POST', '/admin/orders/'.$order_id.'/transactions.json', $arg);
  
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not able to write to the financial_status field to mark an order as paid. The financial_status is a result of the transactions that have taken place on an order. So if an order financial_status is currently authorized, you can mark the order as paid by capturing any funds still owing via our [Transaction API](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/orders/transaction) - or by marking the order as paid within the admin.