# How to create transaction for shopify order created via API

Tags: rest, shopify

I have followed everything in the following [shopify question which is basically the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24340507/how-to-use-the-shopify-api-to-change-the-payment-status-of-orders) but what is described there is not working for me at all. Here is the request I am sending to the transactions endpoint:

```
 {
  "transaction": {
    "amount": "0.01",
    "kind": "sale"
  }
}
```

and here is the response I am getting:

```
 {
  "errors": {
    "kind": [
      "sale is not a valid transaction"
    ]
  }
}
```

I am thinking something has changed with shopify's API since that seemingly duplicate question was answered.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are looking to do?

Comment: I am trying to create a new Order in shopify API and then create a Transaction for that newly created Order in Shopify API for the order total. When I create the Order I am marking it as pending and then when the Transaction is created I am expecting the Order to be marked as paid. The reason I need to create the Transaction is that alot of the third party apps I have for taxes, etc go off of the Transactions in the shop and not the Orders ...since when a normal order is created in the shop on the website, shopify automatically creates a Transaction for each Order placed